# How to find the singular values associated with the largest singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, signal-processing

I have a rectangular complex matrix, and I require to compute the singular vectors (first row and first column) associated with the largest singular value without computing the full SVD decomposition. Can someone indicate what steps should I follow, or refer me to relevant literature?

Comment: Multiply the rectangular matrix by its conjugate transpose to generate a square (aka cross-product) matrix, then apply *Power Iteration* to find its greatest eigenvalue. The eigenvalues of the cross-product matrix equal the singular values of the original matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to find the singular vectors associated with the largest singular value.

Comment: *Power Iteration* also yields the eigenvector associated with the dominant eigenvalue. The dominant eigenvectors of $AA^*$ and of $A^*A$ correspond to the columns of $(U,V)$ associated with the dominant singular value, i.e. $A=USV^*$.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply.